# curvature of a bended piece of paper?

Tags: curvature

According to the Theorema Egregium, a surface that is transformed isometrically, retains its gaussian curvature at every point.

This means that for example a piece of paper cannot be folded into a sphere. We could do it with pizza dough, but paper cannot stretch.

However, If we bend a piece of paper, it is still in some way "curved" (in the intuitive sense).

Similarly, if I'm correct, a cilinder has the same covariant derivative as a flat plane at each point, even though it is in some intuitive sense "curved".

**What would we call this "curvedness" of a cilinder and a bended piece of paper, which don't have gaussian curvature?**

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Th Gaussian curvature of a surface is the [product of two principal curvatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature), so it is null if one of the two curvatures is null. This is the case of a cylinder and of a bended paper.

The not null curvature, in these cases, can be called a normal curvature.